# TapGestureRecognizer not working properly in single click for StackLayout and Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, uitapgesturerecognizer, samsung-galaxy

I have used TapGestureRecognizer for stacklayout and grid in my code and when click it works properly in other device except Samsung S6 galaxy. While double click it works fine.

Code Snippet:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="132">
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="shelfOption_Tapped"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

Am using Xamarin Forms- 2.4.0.282 version. Could you please help me to resolve this?

Regards,

Cheran

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="**FillAndExpand**" **HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand** WidthRequest="132">
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="shelfOption_Tapped"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>

Make VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand, **HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand**  and try
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I tried but didn't works. I have updated Xamarin Forms to 2.5 stable version and now TapGestureRecognizer works properly in Samsung Galaxy S 6 and other device too.

Comment: Great. Works for me. Issue was that tap was not recognizing whole  portion.